# Automorphisms vs General Linear Group typo

Tags: abstract-algebra, automorphism-group, general-linear-group

So given the following math question:

Given commutative ring $R$ and $n \in\mathbb{Z^+}$, show that the automorphism group $\text{Aut}(R^n)\cong \text{GL}_n(R)$ (the general linear group).

First, I found a counterexample with $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $n=1$: the only automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$ is the identity, yet $\text{GL}_1(\mathbb{Z})$ includes both $[1]$ and $[-1]$.  Someone confirmed to me that the problem as stated is incorrect, and that the intended problem would feature modules instead of groups.  Still, given my limited abstract algebra background, that does not enable me to reconstruct the problem as intended.

So, what is the problem supposed to say?

Thank you so much!

Comment: $\varphi(x)=-x$ is also an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$. Prove this.

Comment: You did not find a counterexample. Multiplying by $-1$ is of course an automorphism of $\Bbb Z$. And if $R$ is unital and commutative, the automorphisms of $R^n$ as an $R$-module are indeed represented by invertible $n\times n$ matrices over $R$ (with composition corresponding to matrix multiplication).

Comment: According to http://mathonline.wikidot.com/ring-automorphisms, a ring automorphism must map the identity to the identity.  And rule (2) on that same webpage would also rule out f(x)=-x as an automorphism because $f(-1)\times f(-1)=1\times 1 = 1 \neq f(1) = -1$. So what's up with the discrepancy?

Comment: There are two issues: one is whether you require ring morphisms to be unital (send one to one); if you do, you are correct that $\mathbb{Z}$ has a unique automorphism. But more important is the question of what kind of object one thinks $R^n$ **is**. Is it a ring, or is it an $R$-module? An automorphism of $R^n$ as an $R$-module is not required to be multiplicative, but only additive and homogeneous. If you view $\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, then it does in fact have two automorphisms.

Comment: So what we need is *context*: where is the problem from, and in what context was it given? That would almost certainly clarify whether “the automorphism group” is “the ring automorphism group”, “the unital ring automorphism group”, or “the $R$-module automorphism group”.

Comment: Actually, I'm fairly confident that it means "module automorphism."  The source can be found at https://www.math.arizona.edu/~swc/index.html from Problem 10(b) from Problem Set 2 in the Lori Watson series.

Comment: Well, then it’s not a typo. $\mathbb{Z}$-modules are abelian groups, and the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}$ does indeed have two automorphisms: the identity, and multiplication by $-1$.

Comment: @GeorgeBentley I took a look a look at the problem source, and fwiw I rather think the author slipped up here and not you :) They state just above that for any ring $R$ its group of automorphisms are the isomorphisms $\{\varphi: R\tilde\to R\}$. And for the next subexercise, they give the hint: "The ring homomorphisms we are considering must take multiplicative identities to multiplicative identities." They really must have meant ring automoprhisms.